# How can i determine if its faster to count down or up?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, iteration

I'm trying to make a function `isCountDownFaster(from, to, max);` who should return true/false, but i'm struggling a lot with maths, someone can give a quick hand?

```
0, 1 ... 32, from, 34 ... 66, to, 68 ... 98, max
```

So how can i determine from this ^ if its faster to count down or count up from the point "from" to the point "to"? and i'm 99% sure that there is an equation to do so without using a loop and dozen lines of code.

e.g. isCountDownFaster should determine if counting this way

```
33, 32, 31, ... 2, 1, 0, 99, 98, ... 69, 68, 67
```

will be faster than doing this one

```
33, 34, 35, ... 65, 66, 67
```

which in this case should return `false`.

Comment: How about `(max-from)/2` and check, whether `to` is bigger or less than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function assumes that `from`, `to` and `max` are all non-negative and that `from` and `to` are less than or equal to `max`. `from` and `to` can also equal each other. It favors the direct iteration from `from` to `to` over iterating by wrapping around the array in the case that they are equal length in either direction.

If `from` is equal to `to`, `isCountDownFaster` will always return false because `to >= from` is equal to `true`, making `ascend` equal to `true`, and `direct <= around` will be equal to `true` as well, since `direct` is equal to `0`.

```
function isCountDownFaster(from, to, max) {
    var ascend = to >= from,
        direct = Math.abs(to - from),
        around = max - direct;

    return !!((direct <= around) ^ ascend);
}
```

`!!((direct <= around) ^ ascend)` can be explained like so:

```
direct <= around | ascend | isCountDownFaster
-----------------|--------|------------------
false            | false  | false
false            | true   | true
true             | false  | true
true             | true   | false
```

Here's some test cases to confirm that it's working:

```js
function isCountDownFaster(from, to, max) {
    var ascend = to >= from,
        direct = Math.abs(to - from),
        around = max - direct;

    return !!((direct <= around) ^ ascend);
}

console.log(
    'from: %d\nto: %d\nmax: %d\nisCountDownFaster: %s\n',
    5, 95, 100, isCountDownFaster(5, 95, 100)
);

console.log(
    'from: %d\nto: %d\nmax: %d\nisCountDownFaster: %s\n',
    95, 5, 100, isCountDownFaster(95, 5, 100)
);

console.log(
    'from: %d\nto: %d\nmax: %d\nisCountDownFaster: %s\n',
    45, 55, 100, isCountDownFaster(45, 55, 100)
);

console.log(
    'from: %d\nto: %d\nmax: %d\nisCountDownFaster: %s\n',
    55, 45, 100, isCountDownFaster(55, 45, 100)
);
```

Check the developer console to see these results.

Comment: Note that !! means double negative.

Comment: `!!` is to typecast the `0` or `1` returned by the `^` (XOR operator) into a `Boolean` value.